# C# Avoiding Duplicated Logic

Tags: c#

Suppose I had a base class A, with subclasses B, C and D. I have a class, MyClass which contains an overload for each of them. I want a counter to increment any time one of these methods is invoked from anywhere other than inside MyClass. This can be accomplished with a few simple helper methods:

```
public class MyClass
{
   int counter;

   public doSomethingExternal(B b) {counter++; doSomething(b);}
   public doSomethingExternal(C c) {counter++; doSomething(c);}
   public doSomethingExternal(D d) {counter++; doSomething(d);}

   private doSomething(B b) {...}
   private doSomething(C c) {...}
   private doSomething(D d) {...}
}
```

This really bothers the dev in me. Is there no way better way we can write those helper methods so that we don't have duplicated logic for every subclass? The solution I envision is something like:

```
// Magically, we know which type we are and call the correct doSomething
public doSomethingExternal(A a) {counter++; doSomething(a);}
```

I think this kind of generalization could be accomplished with Reflection, but I have heard that reflection is generally slow and can be complicated to understand. I am curious if there is a more conventional pattern I am overlooking that solves this logic-duplication issue.

Comment: Maybe the [template method pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm) will help you.

Comment: It would be helpful if `A`, `B` and `C` shared something in common, like an interface.

Comment: I think `C#` 7.0 has pattern matching which can help in picking the right method to call.

Answer (score 2):

Well one way you can solve this is to make the classes A, B and C implement an interface. Depending on what the doSomething function is doing you can do something like this.

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void DoSomething();
}
```

then you can have one public function in MyClass.

```
public void doSomethingExternal(IFoo foo)
{
   counter++;
   foo.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: This will move main responsibility(to do something with A,B,C classes) of `MyClass` to classes `A`, `B` and `C`. If `MyClass` do nothing else then you don't need `MyClass` at all.

Comment: Not exactly since the MyClass has a state, the counter. And depending on what the doSomething methods is doing, He could use the foo.DoSomething() and send the MyClass into the method if he would like.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `dynamic`

```
public class MyClass
{
    int counter;

    public doSomethingExternal(A value) // A is base class
    {  
        counter++; 
        dynamic dynamicValue = value;
        doSomething(dynamicValue); // Correct overload will be used based on actual type
    }

    private doSomething(B b) {...}
    private doSomething(C c) {...}
    private doSomething(D d) {...}
}
```

Leaving argument of `doSomethingExternal` to be a base class, will prevent passing other types to the method.

Answer (score -1):

This is clunky and it can be cleaned up with C# 7.0 and pattern matching, but I am not there yet.

```
public interface A { }
public struct B :A { }
public struct C :A { }
public struct D: A { }

public class MyClass
{
    int counter;
    private void DoSomething(B b) { ... }
    private void DoSomething(C c) { ... }
    private void DoSomething(D d) { ... }

    public void DoSomethingExternal(A arg)
    {
        if (arg is B)
        {
            DoSomething((B)arg);
        }
        else if (arg is C)
        {
            DoSomething((C)arg);
        }
        else if (arg is D)
        {
            DoSomething((D)arg);
        }
        else
        {
            // If `A` is not of `B`, `C` or `D` types return without incrementing counter
            return;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

if a common interface or class `A` does not exist, then you have to use `object`.

```
public void DoSomethingExternal(object arg)
{
}
```

Comment: You not using `pattern matching` in your sample. Pattern matching will check for "pattern" and provide instance of result, so your `if` statements should look: `if (arg is B argB) { DoSomething(argB); }`

Comment: @Fabio since I don't have 2017 yet, I could not provide a sample. I am hoping someone else is going to give an answer using C# 7.0

Answer (score -1):

> This really bothers the dev in me. Is there no way better way we can write those helper methods so that we don't have duplicated logic for every subclass?

Why? I actually find your code pretty easy to read. I wouldn't really consider "*duplicate code*", incrementing a simple counter and delegating to a private method. Consider all the alternatives posted? Does any of them make your life any easier?

Of course you could leverage c# 7's pattern matching, but is it really worth it?

```
public void doSomethingExternal(A a)
{
    counter++;

    switch (a)
    {
        case B b:
            doSomething(b);
            break;
        case C c:
            doSomething(c);
            break;
        case D d:
            doSomething(d);
            break;
        case null:
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

All that to simply avoid duplicating `counter++`?

Its your call, we are probably only seeing a very simplified scenario of what your code really looks like and the extent of your "duplicated" logic.